# How to register a source control provider for SVN in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code

I installed the SVN extension of Chris Johnston in Visual Studio Code 1.41.1. With or without explicitly set "svn.path", I do not see any "source control provider".

What do I have to do to enable them?

How do I commit to SVN from Visual Studio Code?